# How to read a JSON file using JSON.simple library?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse a json file using json simple library but I'm having some trouble getting the code to parse the json file. I've done some searching but every example's json file is formatted differently from the one I'm using. I'm able to query the full json file, but I can't get a specific piece of information from my json file and add it to a list (the list turns up empty).

The json file in question (this is a snippet of the original file for simplicity's sake):

```
{
"status": "ok",
"count": "2",
"data":{
    "1":{
        "country": "U.S.A.",
        "name": "Jeremy",
        "id": 1
    },
    "3":{
        "country": "U.K.",
        "name": "Dell",
        "id": 3
    }
}
```

}

The code I've tried using:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String json = myJSONFile; // myJSONFile is a place holder for the location of the file.
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(json);
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("data");
for (int x = 0; y > data.size(); y++)
{
    JSONObject id = (JSONObject) data.get(y + "");
    list.add((String) id.get("name");
}

// Used to show if the list is empty or not.
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list);
```

Comment: That JSON is badly formatted.

Comment: The JSON is invalid and your code snippet wouldn't even compile. Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: Added in the missing commas to the json I provided. I also changed the 2nd name to lessen any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you JSON isn't a valid one. You can try parsing it [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

The correct JSON appears to be:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": "2",
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "country": "U.S.A.",
            "name": "Jeremy",
            "id": 1
        },
        "3": {
            "country": "U.K.",
            "name": "Jeremy",
            "id": 3
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of errors in your code:

1) You are trying to parse the JSON file location without reading it. You need to first read the file containing JSON string

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String json = "..\\json.txt";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object parsed = parser.parse(new FileReader(json));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parsed;
```

2) Your loop doesn't make much sense. Here you want to try and iterate over the keys returned by your `JSONObject` represented by `data`

```
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("data");
Iterator<?> keys = data.keySet().iterator();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
            if (data.get(keys.next()) instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject id = (JSONObject) data.get(keys.next());

                list.add((String) id.get("name"));
                System.out.println("Yo => " + (String) id.get("name"));
            }

        }
```

Here is the full working sample, modify per your need to make it more generic and best practices:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    try {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String json = "..\\json.txt"; //Location of your json file
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        Object parsed = parser.parse(new FileReader(json));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parsed;

        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("data");
        Iterator<?> keys = data.keySet().iterator();

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            if (data.get(keys.next()) instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject id = (JSONObject) data.get(keys.next());

                list.add((String) id.get("name"));
                System.out.println("Yo => " + (String) id.get("name"));
            }

        }

        // Used to show if the list is empty or not.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I had left out the source for the json as it was just a bunch of code that wasn't relevant to the issue at hand. This method managed works perfectly btw. Thanks.